# Access forbidden! CodeIgniter and CodeLobster

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have xampp intalled on my windows computer and I am developing with Codeigniter using CodeLobster environment, and the problem is that every time I click `preview` in any of the php I am working on I get:

> ```
> Access forbidden!
> You don't have permission to access the requested object.
> It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.
> ```

And I can see that CodeLobster is trying to reach to:

```
    http://localhost/mywebsite/application/controllers/project/add.php
```

However, If I want to access successfully I have to access with browser from:

```
    http://localhost/mywebsite/index.php/project/add
```

I checked `base_url` from `config.php` and I think it is pointing in the right direction:

```
    $config['base_url'] = "http://localhost/mywebsite/";
```

Why does CodeLobster go to the wrong direction?

Answer (score 0):

For a framework like CodeIgniter, you are likely going to want to use "Preview via Webserver" in CodeLobster.  I don't have much experience with it, but that should give you the result you are looking for.

Comment: I tried that, but CodeLobster prompts me to download the php file I am trying to open.

Comment: @ericpb make sure your permissions on your directories are set properly and make sure your apache configuration addhandlers are setup to serve php correctly. Check your apache.conf and httpd.conf. There are configuration entries called AddHandler which assign a module to each file extension which should handle this.

Comment: if I were on linux I would give a try with chmod 777 to see if that's the problem. But being in Windows, I can't change permissions on directories.
I don't have apache.conf on Xampp installation, but I do have httpd.conf. It is setted up as:
`AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .asp`